# Is a GMM-HMM equivalent to a no-mixture HMM enriched with more states?

Tags: hidden-markov-model, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I'm trying to model sequence data that has 5 hidden states. Observation data conditional to each state is gaussian except for one state for which mixture of 2 gaussians seems more appropriate. Unfortunately, the R package that I'm using (depmix) does not seem to support (without extending the package) a GMM as a possible response distribution. So I was considering the possibility of adding a 6th state so I could interpret one of this enriched set of states as a state for which observation distribution is the first gaussian in my above mixture and another one as a state for which observation distribution is the second gaussian.

Am I wrong thinking that the two approaches are equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not exactly equivalent: **the 6-state HMM can model everything the GMM-HMM can, but not the other way around.**

Suppose you start with the GMM-HMM, with $s_5$ being the GMM state, and turn it into the 6-state HMM with states $s_6$ and $s_7$ instead of $s_5$.

Let $p_6$ and $p_7$ be the prior probabilities of the two components of the GMM (that are then transformed into states $s_6$ and $s_7$).

For every transition from a state $s_i$ to $s_5$ in the GMM-HMM (with probability $t$), create two transition probabilities in the 6-state HMM:

- $s_i$ to $s_6$ with probability $t \cdot p_6$
- $s_i$ to $s_7$ with probability $t \cdot p_7$

For every transition from $s_5$ to a state $s_i$ in the GMM-HMM (with probability $t$), create two transition probabilities, respectively from $s_6$ and $s_7$, going to $s_i$, both with the same probability $t$.

If I am not mistaken, the resulting 6-state HMM is equivalent to the GMM-HMM.

**However**, the other way around doesn't always work. Imagine you are starting the the 6-state HMM.

Suppose that the transition probabilities for $s_i \rightarrow s_6$ and $s_i \rightarrow s_7$ <strike>are not equal</strike> do not have the same ratio as $s_j \rightarrow s_6$ and $s_j \rightarrow s_7$ (EDIT). You could not carry this information into the GMM-HMM.

**In short, the 6-state HMM should be able to represent everything the GMM-HMM can, and more.**

Comment: I'm not sure that last "suppose" is correct.  What if the mixture probabilities are, say, 0.3 and 0.7?  Wouldn't that imply that the transition probabilities into $s_6$ and $s_7$ weren't equal?

Comment: On the other hand, there is an implication of the GMM that $p_{i,6}/p_{i,7} = p_{j,6}/p_{j,7}$ for all $i,j$, well except the zero transition probabilities of course, which doesn't have to be enforced by the 6-state HMM model, so your fundamental point is correct.

Comment: @jbowman you are correct, I've changed it.

Comment: @VincentB.Lortie so should we conclude that in this case the mixture is better because it's a more parcimonious model?

Comment: First, I would look into how well both fit the data. If the GMM-HMM is really sufficient to model the data, then it should perform comparably to the 6-state HMM, or even better if the 6-state HMM overfits. Then, I suppose you could make a case that the GMM-HMM has fewer parameters than the HMM.

Comment: There's a chance the 6-state HMM will perform better, however, in which case it might be the better option.

Personally, and this is just a matter of taste, I like the 6-state HMM better. I find it less convoluted to add a state to a regular HMM with gaussian states than to turn one of the states into a GMM. Also, it is supported by more software packages.

Answer (score 4):

No you are not wrong thinking that.

If $Y \mid X_1 \sim \alpha f_1(y) + (1-\alpha)f_2(y)$, then you can also let $X_2 \sim \text{Bernoulli}(\alpha)$ independently and say 
$$
Y \mid X_1, X_2 = 1 \sim f_1(y)
$$
and
$$
Y \mid X_1, X_2 = 0 \sim f_2(y).
$$
This is because 
$$
f_{Y|X_1}(y \mid x_1) =  \sum_{i=1}^2f_{Y|X_1,X_2}(y \mid x_1, x_2) f(x_2) = \alpha f_1(y) + (1-\alpha)f_2(y).
$$
Keep in mind the sequence through time $\{X_2^t\}_t$ is iid, and so the Markov structure is overkill (but still perfectly fine).

Comment: could you clarify what do you mean by "Markov structure is overkill"?

Comment: @Patrick I mean iid random sample data are less complicated to analyze than a Markov chain because each element does not rely on the chain's past.  If you wanted to think of $\{X_{2}^t\}$ as a two-state Markov chain, then its transition matrix would have columns with all the same elements.